# Prefix 0 in Razor Textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox

Here is my Razor text box

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShortBufferHour,new { @maxlength = "2",Style="text-align:center;"})
```

It shows the `Hours` as `7`. How to prefix a `0` in case of single digit hour. So that the textbox content be `07`

Comment: Hi, what is the type of your `ShortBufferHour` property?

Comment: It could have been a DateTime formated from your ViewModel, therefore you could have used a proper `string.Format` to return the hour part on two digits.

Comment: we can do like string num = model.ShortBufferHour.ToString("D2"); and convert again 'int' to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `D2` format option and pass the value through as an html atttribute:

This can be done as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShortBufferHour, new { @maxlength = "2",Style="text-align:center;", Value=String.Format("{0:D2}",Model.ShortBufferHour) })
```

Comment: throwing error `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions`

Comment: @iJay Sorry, I hadn't tested that. Please see my updated tested answer. :)